# What is the geographical scope of XBOX Live? Can I play with a friend in India?

Tags: xbox-360

I live in the United States, and I would like to play XBOX Live with a friend in India.  Is this possible, or are there divisions among servers that host different regional players?

Comment: Your account has been properly merged, which now presents you enough reputation to upvote (and the ownership needed to accept).

Answer (score 11):

So you wouldn't think this, but apparently the Xbox Live region for the US does not extend to Canada.  They have their own region up there.  A region I can only imagine is filled with Hockey and Maple Syrup. It's like they're a different country.

I spent some time abroad (where Canada is now defined as abroad for the previously mentioned reasons) and I learned a couple things about Xbox Live:

1. Points in one region do not carry over (ie. you can't use Canadian Xbox Live points on an American Account)
2. Your account is locked to the region you created it in
3. You can use your account in a foreign region (eg. my American account worked in Canada)
4. You can play with people in other regions

That last one seems most relevant to you question.  Not only have I played with friends in Canada (both there and in America), but also friends in England and Germany.  Now I've never tried India, but I'd bet you dollars to samosa, you can.

Although, watch out for that points thing... its really annoying.

Comment: on a completely unrelated note: I *love* samosa

Answer (score 1):

I live in the US and have played against someone who lived in Hong Kong before. (I think I've also played against people who live in Europe ... did a couple of multiplayer games and wasn't entirely sure who was there.)

That doesn't specifically answer your question, but it leads me to believe that you should be able to play against your friend on Xbox Live.

Answer (score -1):

i really don't think you can play with other countries or regions because i haven't played with anybody from other regions and when i watch youtube people from other regions like UK i only here british people. Thats what i think but maybe i am wrong